# jQuery mobile pageinit not firing until after refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I have a page named ChooseType passing parameters to another page, chooseCity with mobile.changePage. When the chooseCity page is loaded the pageinit event doesn't seem to fire until I refresh the page. I have tried pageshow, and beforepagecreate. I have also disabled ajax in the header. Everything I have searched has not come up with a solution. I should mention that my parameters are getting passed along correctly as evidenced by the address bar. Here is my code from chooseType:

```
   <div id="type" data-role="page">
<div class="backgroundLeft">
<div data-role="header" class="heading">
<div class="backButton"><a href="index.html" data-ajax="false"><img src="images/backArrow.png" /></a></div>
    <h1>Best Car Repair Shops</h1>
    </div>

<div data-role="content">
  <div class="choiceList">
<h1>Please choose a shop Type</h1>
</div>
<ul data-role="listview" id="shopTypes" class="mainmenu">
<li><a href="#" class="typemenu" id="D">Diesel Repair</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="typemenu" id="M">Mechanical</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="typemenu" id="P">Paint and Body Shops</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="typemenu" id="R">Tires</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="typemenu" id="T">Transmission</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("pageshow", function(){
  $("#shopTypes li").on("click", "a", function(){
  var type = $(this).attr('id');
  $.mobile.changePage("chooseCity.html",{transition: "slide", data:{type:type}});
});
  });

</script>

</div>

</div>
```

And, my code from chooseCity.html. I am including part of the head that is on all pages:

```
     <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/purl.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="city" data-role="page">
<script src="jquery-mobile/purl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).delegate("#city", "pageshow", function(){
    var url = $.url(document.location); 
    var type = url.param("type");
jQuery(function() {
$.ajax({
url: 'includes/type' + type + '.php',
processData: true,
data:{},
dataType:'json',
success: function(json) {
        $.each(json.shops, function(i, dat){
            var count = dat.count,
                city = dat.City;
    $("#cityMenu").append(
    '<li><a href="#">' + city + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + count + '</span></a></li>');
   });
   $("ul").listview("refresh");
   },
   error: function(x,y,z) {

   }
   });
   });

   });

</script>

<div data-role="header" class="heading">
<div class="backButton"><a href="chooseType.html" data-ajax="false"><img src="images/backArrow.png" /></a></div>
<h1>Best Car Repair Shops</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
<div class="choiceList">
<h1>Please choose a City</h1>
<ul data-role="listview" id="cityMenu" class="mainmenu">

</ul>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: It should be `$(document).on("pageinit", "#city", function () ... });` Its better to place it in `head` of homepage. Edit: chooseCity page will be loaded via Ajax, so anything outside _page_ div will be neglected. That's why `mobileinit` didn't and will never fire.

Comment: @Omar I tried the $(document).on("pageinit", "#city", function () ... }); first. I have tried the function inside the head, and inside the page div to no avail.

Comment: have you placed it in head of first page loaded (homepage)? Try `pagecreate` as `pageinit` is deprecated although it should work until 1.5 is released. do the following changes `$("#city #citymenu").append` and the same for listview refresh.

Comment: @Omar, I also tried placing it in the head of the index page... Still not working.

Comment: Try running basic code like an alert a console.log

Comment: @Omar, got it working. For some reason, my updated code wasn't showing in the browser. Uploaded again, and it is perfect. A little over tired I think. Thank you!